# Scrollspy jumps directly to last tab

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

My HTML code is [here](http://pastebin.com/fGMgMJbR).
My custom css is [here](http://pastebin.com/VMuRvVsL).
I am using Bootstrap 3.3.5 and the scroll spy doesn't work. When the page is loaded it highlights the first tab that is "home" and then after scrolling down it directly points to the last tab of "contact us". Any more information will be provided in comments. Please help. Sorry, the code isn't formatted very well, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Instead of providing separate links to your codes, you can use JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ to place and run your code.

Comment: I tried your code on JSFiddle and it seems to be working fine : https://jsfiddle.net/tusharkhatiwada/g3jbaL43/
Are you sure you've provided all the required libraries : `Jquery`, `Bootstrap CSS` and `Bootstrap JS` ?

Comment: I am using the same source, which I have provided in links. But I have posted a [link](https://youtu.be/HXAQhCeZ16o) to how it behaves in mozilla and chrome.

Comment: Try removing `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollspy.js"></script>` . You don't need this script. `bootstrap.min.js` will do the work.

Comment: I had removed the scrollspy.js but it still didn't work. Although, I did remove some part of last page, I had removed it while pasting it in pastebin. It was an address tag that was creating the problem. I had used tags from bootstrap 2.3.2 which I suppose were causing the problem. Since this part was not there in the pastebin it worked fine on jsfiddle. Thank you for your help. I might have never found out the problem otherwise. It all works fine now!